# Leaving a comment in First Posts queue doesn't enable "I'm done" button until page is refreshed

Tags: support, review

On two different sites (Mi Yodeya and Hermeneutics) today, I left a comment on a post in the First Posts queue.  However, unlike in the past, this did not enable the "I'm done" button.  On Hermeneutics I refreshed the page and the button was enabled; I didn't think to try that on Mi Yodeya.

This happened in Firefox (22.0 for the former, 18 for the latter).  Both queues cleared before I was able to test in Chrome.  I haven't found any populated First Post queues on sites where I have rep to see them, so I'm limited in my ability to test.

Refreshing is a workaround, but is the current behavior correct?  I thought the "I'm done" button was supposed to be enabled as soon as you took some action on the post.

Comment: Is it possible you left the comment from another tab that you had opened to see the entire question? Or did you leave it directly from the review page?

Comment: @jcsanyi, that's a reasonable question to ask (I should have specified), but no, I left the comment right there on the review page, since I could see all the context I needed without separately loading the whole question.